# Instead of intersecting two lists how to intersect more than two?

Tags: java, arraylist

So the structure is `{{Dog,Cat,Human},{Human,Dog,Whale,rabbit,Cow},{Monkey,Human,Dog}}`.

Output should be: `Dog,Human`.

I have to find the intersection of List elements inside the bigger List. Previously, I have seen codes of finding the intersection of separate `ArrayLists`, but not sure how I could do it inside the same `ArrayList` (more than two).

For separate `ArrayLists` a code like the following works. But how do I make it work for multiple `ArrayLists` inside one bigger `ArrayList`? I was asked this in an interview. Worked for separate lists, but couldn't chalk it out for the same `ArrayList`.

The interviewer explicitly stated to work only with Strings, so I modified my Generic type tokens from `{<T>}` to `{<String>}` after the clarification.

```
public class Test {

    public <String> List<String> intersection(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String t: list1) {
            if(list2.contains(t)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Dog", "Cat", "Human"));
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Human", "Dog", "Whale", "rabbit", "Cow"));

        System.out.println(new Test().intersection(list1, list2));

    }
}
```

This produces correct output for two separate `ArrayLists`. However, in case the input is slightly modified, for e.g., the intersection method will return `a,a,a` for the input `a,a,a` and `a,a,` but it will give `a,a` for the input `a,a` and `a,a,a`. The logical assumption would be that it should always return `a,a` regardless of the order of parameters.

Any suggestions as to how I could fix this irrespective of the input order? And how I could find the intersection of several lists (more than two) inside a single bigger list?

Comment: Providing you have a working `intersection` function, you can just repeatedly find the intersection between the list that `intersection` returned, and the new list. In functional oriented languages, you would just fold/reduce the lists of lists using `intersection`.

Comment: If the lists are sorted you can implement it in `O(n)` with a zipper technique. Place a marker on each list, initially at index 0 respectively. Compare all values and if different then advance the marker on all lists that show a smaller value. Continue until marker reach the end of the lists (one is enough for intersection). A commonly used trick in *information retrieval* for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is call the intersection method repeatedly in this fashion-

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Dog", "Cat", "Human"));
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Human", "Dog", "Whale", "rabbit", "Cow"));

    List<List<String>> lists=new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    lists.add(list1);
    lists.add(list2);
    Iterator<List<String>> iterator=lists.iterator();
    List<String>intersect=null;
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        List<String> current=iterator.next();
            if(intersect==null){
              intersect=current;
            }
            else{
                intersect=intersection(intersect,current);
            }
    }
    System.out.println(intersect);
}

public static List<String> intersection(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String t: list1) {
        if(list2.contains(t)) {
            list.add(t);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

}

Comment: I like the approach. However, this is somehow not working. Can you please execute it and check.

Comment: @coder1532 Have a look I put in the entire code. If you like my solution, please accept it and upvote it.

Comment: Works @JoeyPinto

Answer (score 6):

Intersection is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), you can implement intersection of two lists, and then apply the same algorithm repeatedly to the remaining lists.

Java provides a built-in way of doing an intersection through [`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) operation:

```
List<String> a = ...
List<String> b = ...
List<String> c = ...
List<String> intersection = new ArrayList<>(a);
intersection.retainAll(b);
intersection.retainAll(c);
```

Comment: Works.. This way a separate method is not even required.

Answer (score 2):

You can intersect the lists using `Stream` and `filter`:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Dog", "Cat", "Human"));
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Human", "Dog", "Whale", "rabbit", "Cow"));
System.out.println(list1.stream()
            .filter(list2::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

OUTPUT:

```
[Dog, Human]
```

Comment: Nice work @alfasin, but how will this work for multiple lists?

Comment: @JoeyPinto two options (there are probably more): 1. concatenating `.filter(listx::contains)` 2. creating a method that checks if item x is in any of the lists and return true/false, then filtering by calling that method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `intersection` works, just fold the list of lists using `intersection`:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> lists = /* Lists of lists here */;

List<String> finalIntersection =
    lists.stream()
        .reduce(intersection)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Untested, but providing the type of `intersection` matches what `reduce` expects, and `reduce` has an overload that allows for the accumulator to start as the first element, it should work.

Unfortunately, this solution is bloated due to Java only having a `reduce` method for streams. In Clojure (another JVM language), a roughly equivalent snippet of code would simply be:

```
(reduce intersection lists)
```

Which is just lovely.